# Spring Integration | What all comes under it(RestTemplate, @Scheduler, JMS)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-integration

In a recent project requirement, I was asked to not use spring integration for developing the Springboot application.

The application was to collect data from an external API and persist the data in the database. But when I went through the documentation I saw below references,

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/integration.html#spring-integration

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/

Both seem to like talking about different things. Could someone briefly explain what spring integration is and what they are trying to say from the above two links?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Right. There is a general subject interact with third party libraries and protocols called an "integration". That's what the first link is talking about.

The second one is a dedicated Spring project which is fully based on the [Enterprise Integration Patterns](https://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/) and messaging.

Perhaps the name of this project is not the best, but it indeed does all the possible in the world integrations with the same Web, scheduling, JMS etc.

Please, read its docs to understand more.

P.S. You didn't explain in your question why Spring Integration is prohibited in your project.